# Referring to the form backing bean itself in Spring Thymeleaf?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

If I use a form-backing bean in Spring Thymeleaf, is there a way I can refer to the object itself?

Example:

```
<form action="/blah" th:object="${myObject}">
    A field value: [[ *{fieldValue} ]]
    The bean itself the regular way: [[ ${myObject} ]]
    The bean itself using *: [[ *{what_do_I_put_here} ]]
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the special object `#object` in `${...}` expression to access a `th:object` (without having to know it's name on the model).

```
<form action="/blah" th:object="${myObject}">
    A field value: [[ *{fieldValue} ]]
    The bean itself the regular way: [[ ${myObject} ]]
    The bean itself using #object: [[ ${#object} ]]
    A field value using #object: [[ ${#object.fieldValue} ]]
</form>
```